# Is there an unambiguous grapheme for /aʊ/?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

When reading a book I encountered the town/locality "Slough", which got me thinking about how it's one of many towns in Britain that are spelled confusingly (I'm looking at you Gloucester!). But when I tried to amuse myself (don't judge) by thinking about how would I spell it more sensibly I was surprised to find it a struggle. It seems we have no common grapheme mostly unique to /aʊ/? Or am I overlooking one?

"Plough" can be spelled "plow" just like "-ow" in how/cow/now/crown, but of course that's also highly ambiguous: slow/blow/tow/mow/show/flow. "-ough" is of course the most ambiguous/despicable grapheme in English orthography. But every other pronunciation of -ough (off, uff, oh, oo) could be fairly easily spelled more sensibly. The 'oh' version even has several different unambiguous spellings: show -> shoh/sho/shoah/shoe (oops, wtf is shoe spelled like that?). But I can't think of an alternate unambiguous spelling for how/cow/now. Hau/nau/cau? Probably too close to -aw from haughty/naughty/caught. So perhaps I'd need a new grapheme like "ao". It seems maybe Chinese Pinyin beat me to it because that's exactly how its ao final is pronounced: bao, dao, gao, hao, kao, lao, mao, nao, pao, tao, zao, etc.

I mean, does Slao really look any worse than Slough?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142037/discussion-on-question-by-matt-chambers-is-there-an-unambiguous-grapheme-for-a).

Comment: Is there any merit to aow?

Comment: I considered that but Wiktionary has one counterexample where it is /aʊw/: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laowai

Comment: How did this get closed with no comments mentioning it as opinion-based? Is spelling reform off topic on this site??

Comment: Lao'wai is a Chinese loanword and AFAIK the lao and wai are separate syllables. I gave credit to Pinyin for -ao but actually they copied it from the earlier Wade-Giles Romanization. Hao is your cao doing nao? :D The w suffix would make sense though with consonants coming after it: craon/craown, braon/braown.

Answer (score 2):

Having spent some time researching this, I haven't been able to find one. English rarely has unambiguous graphemes for vowel sounds due to its high orthographic depth (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_depth)).

**Edit:** Before you suggest "ao" as in Chinese loanwords, consider the word "aorist."

Comment: Aorta is common enough: all humans have one. Then there's 'gaol' and 'chaos'. Actually there's quite a few 'ao' words where it's a vowel hiatus (like aorta and chaos).  I won't count 'karaoke'. There is 'haole' which is a Hawaiian transcription that mirrors the Pinyin pronunciation of 'hao' but not 'le'. But even considering those, ao looks pretty good for /aʊ/.